# How Do I Use Indexed with NIntegrate in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm having trouble using

```
Indexed[]
```

with

```
NIntegrate[]
```

in Mathematica.  I want to evaluate something like

```
NIntegrate[Indexed[t, 1], {Indexed[t, 1], 0, 1}]
```

with a lot more variables (indices).  However, I receive this error:

```
"Tag Indexed in Indexed[t,1] is Protected"
```

I'm fairly certain the problem arises from the second argument because

```
NIntegrate[Indexed[x, 1]^2 Indexed[x, 2]^2, x \[Element] Rectangle[]]
```

evaluates as I would expect.
I have tried unprotecting the second argument and wrapping it with an evaluate and neither worked.  I think I need to use

```
Indexed[]
```

because I have a complicated expression over a complicated region with a variable number of dimensions.  I have to use

```
NIntegrate[]
```

because

```
Integrate[]
```

failed to solve my integral, but otherwise performed as I expected with, for example,

```
Integrate[Indexed[t, 1], {Indexed[t, 1], 0, 1}].
```

I am using Mathematica 10.0.

Comment: you can not use the result of indexed as an integration variable. use `t[1] ,t[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is the purpose of Indexed in your case.
If that is just for the decoration I would suggest using Subscript instead of Indexed. Try this

```
NIntegrate[Subscript[t, 1], {Subscript[t, 1], 0, 1}]
```

It works on Mathematica 10.0

Comment: I needed the output from NIntegrate to look like a proper mathematical expression so it could be compared to a prediction easily.  I guess that makes it "for decoration".  As a bonus, your answer can be properly copied as Latex.